# How can I create a lambda expression to get all the dates in between 2 dates?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm very new to lambda expressions and want to know how to get all the dates which are between x date and y date. So far I have written it to get all of the data based on the id of an object but now I need to write code to get the data based on id, start date and end date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
data = ClientsRepo.GetAllClients().DistinctBy(x => x.ClientID);
```

my start date and end date is in my razor page which is defined here:

```
@code{
DateTime? startDateInit;
DateTime? endDateInit;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    startDateInit = DateTime.Now;
    endDateInit = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
}


}
```

Comment: Who closed this?  That thread is NOT a duplicate of this question.  "Getting dates between" and "Searching dates between" are not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 ugh, you're right.  I edited it earlier today to what you saw because I am apparently bad at reading.  I've changed it back.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: What does each record in `ClientsRepo` - `Client` I'm assuming - look like, specifically the date field you want to filter on?

Comment: `DistinctBy` is not really a search function. Making some assumptions that you want all records within the dates that match an id: `data = ClientsRepo.GetAllClients().Where(x => x.ClientID == myClientID && x.ClientDate >= startDateInit && x.ClientDate <= endDateInit).ToList();`

Comment: @SteveGreene Hi, steve, thank you for that lambda exp. It was all I needed!